# XML Node Update Using VBA

Tags: xml, vba

I have XML Data like

```
<Main>
<sub>data</sub>
<sub2>data2<sub2>
<sub3>data3<sub3>
</main>
```

how can we update data with New data using VBA variable

```
Dim newdata
newdata = "New Data"
```

And Get XML LIKE

```
<Main>
<sub>New data</sub>
<sub2>data<sub2>
<sub3>data<sub3>
</main>
```

Comment: Start here [Parsing XML Files With VBA In Excel](https://www.sudanec.com/2020/04/14/parsing-xml-files-with-vba-in-excel/) and if you run into any problems post your code with the XML example in another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the next function. It uses `RegEx`:

```
Function UpdateNode(strText As String, strTag As String, strReplace As String) As String
     With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "<" & strTag & ">(.*)</" & strTag & ">"
        UpdateNode = .Replace(strText, "<" & strTag & ">" & strReplace & "</" & strTag & ">")
    End With
End Function
```

Test it using the next `Sub`:

```
Sub testUpdateNode()
    Dim txt As String
    txt = "<Main> " & vbCrLf & _
            "   <sub>data</sub>" & vbCrLf & _
            "   <sub2>data2</sub2>" & vbCrLf & _
            "   <sub3>data3</sub3>" & vbCrLf & _
            "</main>"
    Debug.Print UpdateNode(txt, "sub", "New Data")
    Debug.Print UpdateNode(txt, "sub2", "New Data")
End Sub
```

Take care to have a correct XML ("sub2", "sub3" missing ending slash "/")...

If there are more occurrences of the tag to be updated, the next version can  be used:

```
Function UpdateNodes(strText As String, strTag As String, strReplace As String) As String
     Dim M As Object, i As Long
     With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "<" & strTag & ">(.*)</" & strTag & ">"
        If .Test(strText) Then
            Set M = .Execute(strText)
            For i = 0 To M.count - 1
                strText = Replace(strText, M(i), "<" & strTag & ">" & strReplace & "</" & strTag & ">")
            Next i
        End If
    End With
    UpdateNodes = strText
End Function
```

And test it in the same way:

```
  Debug.Print UpdateNodes(txt, "sub2", "New Data")
```

To have a different you should modify the string to be processed, to make it having two such tags...

```
   txt = "<Main> " & vbCrLf & _
         "   <sub>data</sub>" & vbCrLf & _
         "   <sub2>data2</sub2>" & vbCrLf & _
         "   <sub2>data3</sub2>" & vbCrLf & _
         "</main>"
```

Comment: Thank You Very much. It works for me. To Replace Data for <Sub>.
addition to that i am facing issue like If there is no <SUB3> then it cant replace it
how to get if it exits or not and how to add SUB3

Comment: @Kush Tiwari I cannot get you... I mean, I cannot understand your question. If you do not have any <sub3> tag, nothing will be replaced. What else do you need for such a situation? Don't you understand how to call it in order to search and replace for this <sub3> tag? I cannot suppose that...

Comment: If there is no SUB3 Then I want To add Sub3 In XML with data
1 I want to check if there is sub3 in XML or not 
2 If there is sub3 then Replace Data (you help with this)
3 if there is no SUB3 Than add SUB3

Comment: @Kush Tiwari Then, who stops you to add it? Do you mean to make the code to add it if not found? If so, a xml file may be very complex and how the code to know where to insert the respective tag? If you really need that, you should place another question showing the existing code and clearly describe what is to be done if the tag has not been fount. You should also better describe the structure of the xml file and the logic based on what the new tag to be inserted... This is a different issue!